# Latex beamer: Remove indent in itemize

Tags: beamer, itemize

I'm using the beamer class and would like to remove the indentation created for items in the itemize environment.

I have tried the following solutions:

- the enumitem usepackage - just loading it removes all bullet points entirely
- \setlength{\itemindent}{-1em} before the item. It only removes the indentation of the first line of an item, but if the item is multi-lined, the other lines are still indented.

This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Frame Title}
Some text
\begin{itemize}
%\setlength{\itemindent}{-1em}
    \item first item
    \item this is a second item which is longer and should hopefully go over more than one line
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't try to use the `enumitem` package with beamer -- they are incompatible.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Is this the layout you are looking for?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Frame Title}
Some text
\settowidth{\leftmargini}{\usebeamertemplate{itemize item}}
\addtolength{\leftmargini}{\labelsep}
\begin{itemize}
    \item first item
    \item this is a second item which is longer and should hopefully go over more than one line
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for, thanks very much!

Comment: @Jaran You're welcome!

Comment: Helped me too!! Many thanks!

Comment: I even used `\addtolength{\leftmargini}{\labelsep -.75cm}` to make it wider without needing to widen the column environment !

Comment: can we make this setting globally for all the `itemize` ?

Comment: Exactly what I was trying to do. Thanks for saving my day.

Comment: @shafee You're welcome! Have fun with beamer :)

Comment: @alper Just move the two lines of code before `\begin{document}`.